# Wordpress Edit Page Textareas

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was tasked with migrating a CodeIgniter Site to WordPress in order to allow interns to edit the pages. Some of the pages have extremely complex html structures. I saw a video where additional textareas were added to the Edit Page page and each textarea corresponded to a specific div on the page. If I could duplicate this, the interns could edit small chunks of the page at a time rather than crippling the entire page due to carelessness. They've done this twice already and the WordPress site has been up for three days.

I tried to google for this but since I don't really know what they are called, I was unsuccessful. I am looking to be pointed in the right direction here -- I can do the research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with custom fields http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

The advanced-custom-fields plugin, for example, gives you plenty of possibilities for adding custom forms on your post pages using textareas and whatnot
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields